# Extract text between certain characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following link structure (example, link can't be joined):

```
https://zoom.us/j/345678634?pwd=fdgSDdfdfasgdgJEeXNaRjNBZz09
```

My goal is to extract two numbers in two different cells

First one:
345678634

I tried:
`(?<=/j/).(?=?pwd)`

Second one:
fdgSDdfdfasgdgJEeXNaRjNBZz09

I tried (besides others):
`(?<=?pwd).`

What I thought about is for the second one just everything that's behind `?pwd=` and for the first one everything that's between `/j/` and `?pwd=`. I just don't know how to get this done with regex.

Comment: Please look at the second alternative provided by JvdV. It'll help you too. If it helps please consider accepting his answer since it provides you more flexibilty with and without direct regex. And  until and unless you're not bound to use only regex; inbuilt functions are relatively faster and more efficient than regexes therefore that might be the favorable choice.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
.*?\/j\/(\d+)\?pwd=(\w+)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`.*?`** - Matches **lazily** everything before `j`.
- **`\/j\/`** - Matches `/j/` literally.
- **`(\d+)`** - Represents first capturing group matching digits 1 or more times.
- **`\?`** - Matches `?` literally.
- **`pwd=`** - Matches `pwd=` literally.
- **`(\w+)`** - Represents second capturing group capturing the word characters i.e. `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` one or more times.

[image]

### You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/6Nq588/4)

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you Mandy8055. Very helpful!

Comment: @JoeyCoder I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately lookarounds are not supported (AFAIK) in RE2. But it seems like you could use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d+).*=(.*)")
```

[image]

- `(` - Open 1st capture group.

  - `\d+` - Match at least a single digit.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `.*` - Match zero or more characters (greedy)
- `=` - Match a literal `=`.
- `(` - Open 2nd capture group.

  - `.*` - Match any character other than newline zero or more times.
  - `)` - Close 2nd capture group.

Because of the *spill* feature both groups will be extracted into neighboring cells.

---

A 2nd option, if you want to avoid `REGEX`, is using `SPLIT` and `QUERY`. However, depending on your data, I'm not sure which one would be faster in processing:

```
=QUERY(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?pwd=","/"),"/"),"Select Col4,Col5")
```

Comment: I don't understand how that REGEX works, but indeed it is my desired result. Could you maybe explain me what's happening in it?

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Very interesting how you and Mandy have complete different solutions but both work.

Comment: It's not completely different though. His is just more precise, looking at restrictions you have mentioned. Mine is made on the assumption your string pattern would always be the same.